# The appearance and increase of the circle by left click

Tags: python, pygame

I have such a task:

> Write a program in which, by clicking the left mouse button, a circle
> appears at the place of the click, constantly growing and increasing
> in diameter.

I wrote code with which I have a circle at a certain point, which begins to increase. When I click with the left mouse button, the circle moves to the click point, but continues to grow, although it should start from the beginning.

I'm just learning Python,and I can't figure out how to make the circle start over again every time.

I would be very grateful for your help, and sorry for my English.

My code:

```
import pygame

size = width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 30

MintCream_COLOR = (245, 255, 250)
LightSkyBlue_COLOR = (135, 206, 250)

x = y = 40

def draw(radius):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, LightSkyBlue_COLOR, (x, y), radius)
r = 0

running = True
pygame.display.update()

while running:
    screen.fill(MintCream_COLOR)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            x, y = event.pos[0], event.pos[1]

    draw(r)
    r = r + 1

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: reset the radius

Comment: @JanWilamowski I would be very grateful if you could show me how I can do this

Comment: Ok, so I'm not exactly sure how pygame works, but you will need to reset your radius (r) variable as @Jan Wilamowski said. Your current code resets it once. You will need to change it so that 'r = 0' will be executed each time you click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
!pip install pygame
import pygame

size = width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 30

MintCream_COLOR = (245, 255, 250)
LightSkyBlue_COLOR = (135, 206, 250)

x = y = 40

def draw(radius):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, LightSkyBlue_COLOR, (x, y), radius)
r = 0

running = True
pygame.display.update()
click = False

while running:
    screen.fill(MintCream_COLOR)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            r=0
            click = True
            x, y = event.pos[0], event.pos[1]

    if click == True:
        draw(r)
        r = r + 1

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you have is that you use the r variable every time without changing its value. It is incrementing and in any place of the code, you do not change it to 0 again.

The only thing you have to do is to set the r variable to 0 when the user clicks the screen:

```
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
        r = 0
        x, y = event.pos
```

You can see that the x and y variables are easier to set than you did. Just type Python tuple unpacking on the Internet and get to know with it.